# notifiyDataSetChanged() makes listview disappear until touch

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I use the code below to initialize and refresh a ListView. When the fragment is loaded and the function called the first time, the listview get populated with no problem. Now if I call the same function again, the listview disappears and only reappears with the new data when I start to scroll, touch the screen or rotate the devices etc... I've also tried to call that function on UI thread with no success. This fucntion is called from a Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener.

```
private void setList() {
    ArrayList<Message> list = new ArrayList<Message>();

    SaxFeedParser sfp;
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    switch (mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
    case 0:
        sfp = new SaxFeedParser(1);
        messages = sfp.parse();
        sfp = new SaxFeedParser(2);
        messages.addAll(sfp.parse());
        break;
    case 1:
        sfp = new SaxFeedParser(1);
        messages = sfp.parse();
        break;
    case 2:
        sfp = new SaxFeedParser(2);
        messages = sfp.parse();
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
        list.add(messages.get(i));
    }

    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list,
            (MainActivity) getActivity());
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mList.invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the spinner from the holoeverywhere library I used. It has a bug that has something to do with focus management but I wasn't able to analyse it more precisely. Clicking on the screen just gave back the focus to the list and the view was refreshed.

I ended up not using holoeverywhere for that spinner.